# Websocket by swift error with package version mismatch kodeco

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, vapor

I am trying to learn websocket with Swift. I have started to learn from [kodeco](https://www.kodeco.com/home) [An Introduction to WebSockets](https://www.kodeco.com/13209594-an-introduction-to-websockets).

But to build the `starter project` I am facing a few version mismatches of a few packages.

**SQLite kit package error**

```
The package product 'SQLiteNIO' requires minimum platform version 13.0 for the iOS platform, but this target supports 11.0
```

**vapor package error**

```
The package product 'Crypto' requires minimum platform version 13.0 for the iOS platform, but this target supports 11.0
```

**with below config in `Package.swift` above error occurs**

```
 name: "websocket-backend",
  platforms: [
    .macOS(.v10_15)
  ],
```

But if I set **iOS** manually by the below code in `Package.swift` error sustained.

```
platforms: [
    .macOS(.v10_15), .iOS(.v13)
  ],
```